# Do I need Bower for front end dependencies when I am already using composer?

Tags: php, javascript, css, dependencies

I use composer for PHP dependencies. I was under the impression that for front end dependencies I should use Bower. So, I installed Bower and loaded my FE dependencies (Bootstrap, jQuery) using that. I then manually symlink to the libraries as follows:

```
mypc:/var/www/myproject/public/js$ ls -l
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tom tom   67 Dec 23 07:29 bootstrap.min.js -> /var/www/myproject/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tom tom   58 Dec 23 07:29 jquery.min.js -> /var/www/myproject/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

However, I notice that these are stored within a directory /bower_components just as composer dependencies are stored in /vendor. So now I have /bower_components and /vendor as well as /node_modules (for grunt and grunt plugins). So as all Bower does it bring down the repositories, upon which I need to link to them - can I not just use composer for front end libraries too?

```
"components/jquery": "dev-master"
"components/bootstrap": "dev-master"
```

.. then create symlinks to the files (e.g. .js .css) in my public/* directories? Is there any reason whhy Bower is still better for managing FE dependencies? Thanks

Comment: This would only work of course if those front end libraries have a corresponding repo on packagist.org.

Comment: Just wait until you can't find a package on Bower and need to use npm also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Composer is a dependency manager for PHP only while Bower is optimized for front end dependencies that can be used with not only sites built with PHP but built with other programming languages and frameworks. I would stick with Bower for front end dependency management as that's what its designed for. :)

Comment: Even though it's true that Composer was created to manage PHP packages, it's interesting to note that some front-end frameworks are now installable via Composer, such as [Foundation](https://packagist.org/packages/zurb/foundation) and [Bootstrap](https://packagist.org/packages/twitter/bootstrap).

Answer (score 6):

I just stumbled across this gem that will allow you to use Composer with Bower packages:

https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin

From their Readme:

> The Composer Asset Plugin allows you to manage project assets (css,
>   js, etc.) in your `composer.json` without installing NPM or Bower.
>
> This plugin works by transposing package information from NPM or Bower
>   to a compatible version for Composer. This allows you to manage asset
>   dependencies in a PHP based project very easily.
>
> Features include:
>
> - Works with native management system versions of VCS repository of composer
> - Works with public and private VCS repositories
> - Lazy loader of asset package definitions to improve performance
> - Import filter with the dependencies of the root package and the installed packages, for increased dramatically the performance for the
>     update
> - Automatically get and create an Asset VCS repository defined in:
>
>   - [NPM Registry](https://www.npmjs.org)
>   - [Bower Registry](http://bower.io/search)
> - Automatically get and create the Asset VCS repositories of dependencies defined   in each asset package (dev dependencies
>     included)
> - Mapping conversion of asset package to composer package for:
>
>   - [NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/package.json.html) - package.json
>   - [Bower Package](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages) - bower.json
> - Conversion of Semver version to the composer
>     version
> - Conversion of Semver range version to the
>     composer range version
> - Conversion of dependencies with URL to the
>     composer dependencies with the creation of VCS repositories
> - Conversion of multiple versions of the same dependency
>     to different dependencies of composer
> - Add manually the multiple versions of a same dependency in the project
> - Add a custom config of VCS Repository
> - Override the config of VCS Repository
>     defined by the asset registry directly in extra section of root
>     composer
> - VCS drivers for:
>
>   - Git
>   - GitHub (compatible with repository redirects)
>   - Git Bitbucket
>   - Mercurial
>   - Mercurial Bitbucket
>   - SVN
>   - Perforce
> - Local cache system for:
>
>   - package versions
>   - package contents
>   - repository redirects
> - Custom asset installers configurable in the root file `composer.json`
> - For Bower, all files defined in the section `ignore` will not be installed
> - Disable or replace the deleting of the ignore files for Bower
> - Enable manually the deleting of the ignore files for NPM
> - Use the Ignore Files Manager in the Composer scripts
> - Compatible with all commands, including:
>
>   - `depends`
>   - `diagnose`
>   - `licenses`
>   - `remove`
>   - `require`
>   - `search` (bower only)
>   - `show`
>   - `status`